# Plot by variable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a shiny App with simulated newborn data. I want that according to the variable that is selected, a historical graph be made in the other box (counts per day, per variable). 
Data looks like this:

```
         date sex intubated support
1  2010-01-01   M         1       4
2  2010-01-01   F         0       2
3  2010-01-01   M         0       2
4  2010-01-01   M         1       3
5  2010-01-01   F         0       1
6  2010-01-02   F         1       2
7  2010-01-02   F         1       2
8  2010-01-02   F         0       2
9  2010-01-02   M         0       4
10 2010-01-03   M         0       2
11 2010-01-03   F         0       1
12 2010-01-03   M         1       1
13 2010-01-03   M         0       1
14 2010-01-03   F         1       3
```

The code runs without errors, but graph's box just remains blank, not even the blank ggplot appears. Can someone help me to know what is missing? Thank you!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rio)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

data_n <- import("BD.xlsx")
data_n$date <- as.Date(data_n$date)
data_n$sex <- factor(data_n$sex)
data_n$intubated <- factor(data_n$intubated)
data_n$support <- factor(data_n$support)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",

                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),       
                    dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                        box(
                          title = "Controller panel", status = "info", solidHeader = T,
                          "Choose date and variable", collapsible = T,
                          dateRangeInput(inputId = "range", 
                                         label = "Choose data range",
                                         format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),
                          varSelectInput("var", "Choose variable",
                                         data = data_n,
                                         multiple = F,
                                         selected = NULL,
                                         selectize = T),
                          actionButton(inputId = "go", 
                                       label = "Refresh")
                          ),
                        box(
                          title = "Plot", status = "info", solidHeader = T,
                          collapsible = T,
                          plotOutput("plot_neo")
                        )
                      )
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    dataInput <- reactive({
      subset(data_n, date >= input$range[1] & date <= input$range[2])
    })

    plotInput <- eventReactive(input$go, {

      if (input$var == "sex"){
      ggplot(data = dataInput(), aes(x=date, y = sex))+
          geom_line()
      }
      if (input$var == "intubated"){
        ggplot(data = dataInput(), aes(x=date, y = intubated))+
          geom_line()
      }
      if (input$var == "support"){
        ggplot(data = dataInput(), aes(x=date, y = support))+
          geom_line()
      }

    })

    output$plot_neo <- renderPlot({
        plotInput()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This might be more a problem with your plotting than shiny. Did you make desired plots outside of shiny to get what you want already? Did you want line plots of counts or frequencies per day for sex, intubated, or support columns?

Comment: Yes! i want to count per day, every variable (lines or columns). I tried a single variable without using "If" and it works, using bars:ggplot(data = dataInput(), aes(x=date, fill = sex))+geom_bar(). Maybe I didn't write the lines one well. Every time I use "If" inside a reactive event, it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: I just put in `if (input$var == "sex"){
      ggplot(data = dataInput(), aes(x=date, fill = sex))+
        geom_bar()
    }` in the `plotInput` expression and it worked fine for me if that variable was selected. Could you edit your question with the exact code that didn't work so I can reproduce? Also, can you use `dput(head(data_n))` and add results to your question as well?

Comment: Thank you. I tried a single If, like you, and it worked. But I used two If, first "sex" and then "intubated", but it only shows the "intubated" graph, and not the "sex" graph. In fact when I try with three variables", only the support graph appears, no more.
In addition to this, how can I make a similar line graph? where each line is a category.

Comment: `structure(list(date = structure(c(14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 
14610, 14610), class = "Date"), sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), intubated = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    support = structure(c(4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but hope this will help.

Instead of multiple `if` statements, you can just make sure the `input$var` selected is one of the 3 variables of interest (sex, intubated, or support). `isolate` is included so the plot is not automatically redrawn, until `input$go` is selected as you currently have it.

You can use `aes_string` and pass in `input$var` which has the character value of the column you wish to plot. If you want the line plots with counts, you can use `geom_line(stat = 'count')`.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    subset(data_n, date >= input$range[1] & date <= input$range[2])
  })

  plotInput <- eventReactive(input$go, {       
    if (c(isolate(input$var)) %in% c("sex", "intubated", "support")) {
      ggplot(data = dataInput(), aes_string(x = "date", group = input$var, color = input$var)) +
        geom_line(stat = 'count')
    }       
  })

  output$plot_neo <- renderPlot({
    plotInput()
  })

}
```